# Display Information with CRUD Controller (EasyAdmin 4 + Symfony 7)

Tags: php, symfony, twig, easyadmin

I would like to know if there's a way to include content with a CRUD controller using EasyAdmin 4 with Symfony 7. I've read all documentation and searched on the internet, but I couldn't find any solutions.

For example, I have a CRUD controller for "keywords":

[image: EasyAdmin keyword CRUD controller]

And the keywords are related to "works". I know how to filter the keywords list for a given work, and operate accordingly. I would like to know if there's a way to display further information about the selected work when filtering the keywords in the CRUD controller, for example (I did it on Paint):

[image: Desired result]

Probably the way EasyAdmin created the templates as modules, allowing the user to replace parts of the forms, there's a solution like that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to obtain such result by overriding block `main` on `index.html.twig` template. Something like:

```
{% extends '@!EasyAdmin/crud/index.html.twig' %}

{% block main %}
    Put your code here.
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

The `parent()` call is needed to display the table after your changes.

On the CRUD controller, there's the need to inform the override:

```php
public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
{
    return parent::configureCrud($crud)
        ->overrideTemplate('crud/index', 'admin/crud/index.html.twig')
    ;
}
```

The file can be anywhere inside `templates` folder, or if you prefer, use Symfony mechanism to override templates.